# Weyl Operator Group Actions

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

For $g \in L^2(\mathcal{R})$ and real numbers $p$ and $q$, denote $g^{(p,q)}(t) = e^{ipt}g(t-q)$. Calculate $||g^{(p,q)}||, M_t(g^{(p,q)}), M_{\omega}(g^{(p,q)}), \sigma_t(g^{(p,q)}),$ and $\sigma_{\omega}(g^{(p,q)})$.

---

**My Attempt**

For starters, I know

\begin{align}
M_t(g^{(p,q)}) &= \int_R t|g^{(p,q)}(t)|^2 dt\\
&=\int_R t|e^{ipt}g(t-q)^2|dt\\
&= \int_R t|g(t-q)|^2 dt
& \text{let } u=t-q \text{ and } t=u+q\\
&= \int_R(u+q)|g(u)|^2 du\\
&= \int u|g(u)|^2 du + q\int (g(u))^2 du\\
&= M_t(g) + q
\end{align}

I'm guessing
\begin{equation}
M_{\omega}(g^{(p,q)}) = \int\omega|\hat{g}^{(p,q)}(\omega)|d\omega
\end{equation}
but I'm not sure how to find $\hat{g}^{(p,q)}(\omega)$

I know I should end up with 
\begin{equation}
M_{\omega}(g^{(p,q)}) = M_{\omega}(g)+p
\end{equation}

Comment: I have added some more of my work in the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

The transform is $\hat{g}^{(p,q)} = e^{iq\omega}\hat{g}(\omega-p)$, which can be seen by substituting directly into the equation for the fourier transform and substituting $u=t-q$ in the integral. This makes the work for $M_\omega$ the same as that for $M_t$.

I'm not familiar with $\sigma_t$, but if you post the formula I'll work with it.

Edit: With PNB's help, $\sigma_t^{(p,q)}=\int (t-M_t)^2 |g^{(p,q)}|^2dt=\int (u+q-M_t(g^{(p,q)}))^2 |g^{(p,q)}|^2du=$

$\int (u-M_t(g))^2 |g^{(p,q)}|^2du=\sigma_t$

Comment: @PostNoBills I've updated the result. You should check it; I just winged it.